# Creating a SOCKS 5 Proxy on iPad

Tags: ios, proxy, client-server, socks

I have a desktop application that does file transfer between a client and a server using FTP. In order to make a connection between client and a server it uses a SOCKS 5 proxy server written by us only. I want to port this application to iOS devices. Is there any support on iPad/IPhone to create a FTP application that uses a SOCKS 5 proxy in between to create a connection.

Thanks,
A.S

Comment: I don't want to use .PAC file.

Comment: Did you ever find the solution for this SOCKS 5 Proxy with iOS app